# "memcpy must be given valid pointers": where can I find this in the standard?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, memcpy

[It is stated on cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) that

> If either `dest` or `src` is an invalid or null pointer, the behavior is undefined, even if `count` is zero

Same is stated for `memset` and `memmove`.

My question is: where is it stated in the standard? I need to justify this as an UB to my client, but a link to a cppref article won' t do, I need the reference in the standard.

[Public draft of the standard](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf)

Comment: You can trust cppreference to be true (even if it is not written in standardese). Also I wouldn't use ::memcpy (memset and memmove) anyway, there is std::copy (or std::bit_cast for type punning) which is more (typesafe) safe to use. And they will not be slow. The C++ standard by the way refers to the "C" standard for memset (which makes sense it is there as a backward compatible option in C++)

Comment: Well, it is not I who uses ::memcpy, it is the client, and my job is to detect UBs which I do. Whether they will change it or not to std::cpy is up to them, that' s why I want to point the standard section that says so. I do trust cppref, but I need more than just this as a proof

Comment: Detecting UB is impossible, because by the time it happend your program is no longer in a valid state. Or do you want to detect invalid input to your own implementation of memcpy? Or Something is not clear to me here.

Comment: It is indeed possible to detect UB: I work for a company that developped a tool to do it. It's called Trust-in-soft (look it up). My job is to use the tool to audit our clients' code.

Comment: Oh static analyis, I assumed at runtime. At least it is much more clear now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++ standard refers the C standard, and these functions are defined in the C standard.

#### 7.24 String handling <string.h>

##### 7.24.1 String function conventions

2. <...> Unless explicitly stated otherwise in the description of a particular function in this subclause, pointer arguments on such a call shall still have valid values, as described in 7.1.4. <...>

##### 7.1.4 Use of library functions

1. <...> If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as a value
   outside the domain of the function, or a pointer outside the address space of the program, or a null pointer, or a pointer to non-modifiable storage when the corresponding parameter is not const-qualified) or a type (after promotion) not expected by a function with variable number of arguments, the behavior is undefined <...>

[C17 ISO/IEC 9899:2018 N2310](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf)

Comment: And which part of the C++ standard incorporates the C standard?  I don't believe it does, they're independent.

Comment: [cstring.syn#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/cstring.syn#1) The contents and meaning of the header <cstring> are the same as the C standard library header <string.h>. [support.c.headers.general#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/support.c.headers.general#1)  It is possible that C++ source files need to include one of these headers in order to be valid ISO C. Source files that are not intended to also be valid ISO C should not use any of the C headers.

Comment: @MarkRansom C++ standard does refer to C standard (and few others). In particular, C++20 refers to ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C17). I believe the relevant part declaring the C subpart in C++ is https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf#subsubsection.16.5.1.2